# How to write query sql on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel 4. I have Query Sql Like this

```
SELECT at.test_id, MAX(at.result), COUNT(status_assessment_id='2') FROM recruitment_process a LEFT JOIN recruitment_result at ON a.id = at.recruitment_id GROUP BY test_id
```

I do not know how can I write this on Laravel 4?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.2?

Comment: hy  ARIF MAHMUD RANA yes I'm using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked but you can try this

```
DB::table('recruitment_process a')
    ->select('at.test_id', DB::raw('MAX(at.result)'), DB::raw('COUNT(status_assessment_id="2")'))
    ->leftJoin('recruitment_result at', 'a.id', '=', 'at.recruitment_id')
    ->groupBy('at.test_id')
    ->get();
```

More details here https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be:

```
DB::table('recruitment_process')
    ->select(
    array('recruitment_result.test_id', 
           DB::raw('COUNT(status_assessment_id='2') as mycount'), 
           DB::raw('MAX(recruitment_result.result) as maxvalue')))
    ->left_join('recruitment_result', 'recruitment_process.id', '=', 'recruitment_result.recruitment_id')
    ->group_by('test_id')
    ->get();
```

Not sure if there is any faster or more effective way.

Comment: matt yah meybe it's not effective way. but I'm appreciate you have answer I will try